# How to make a graph of coefficient estimate like this in Stata?

Tags: graph, stata

[graph from Cantoni 2014](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F61N.png)
How to plot coefficient estimate like this in Stata?

It is a cross-section panel data like this:

`city year gdp church 
A    1996 2000  23
A    1997 2200  25
A    1998 2500  30
B    1996 2800  20
...`

I want to see the influence of gdp on number of church, and I use fixed effect model with `xtreg church gdp, fe robust`
How can I make a plot of the coefficient estimate?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that and I have edited my question. Hope that is clear now.

Comment: Unclear: the gdp coefficient is a single number. So plot of what against what?

Comment: The attachment is just a graph. No one should be expected to recognise a reference "Cantoni 2014" or to work out from the graph exactly how it was reproduced.

Comment: I am so sorry I did not make it clear. The author wanted to know the influence of protestantism on the economic prosperity in Germany. He also used a panel data and the model was OLS. His independent variable is a dummy, whether the city is a Protestant city or Catholic city and dependent variable is log city size. In the question I looked into inverse relationship, effects of economy on religion. I assumed the principles for visualizing the relationship were similar. I am very sorry.

Comment: Neither your description or the `xtreg` model in your question shows a regression which estimates a separate coefficient for each year.

Answer (score 1):

1. Any reference to "cross-section panel data" is wrong. A dataset can be **either** cross-section data, when different units are sampled at each time point, **or** panel data. From the context I infer this is a panel dataset.
2. Number of churches is a positive discrete variable, while OLS assumes a continuous response variable. This can induce problems, as out-of-bound predictions. So I suggest a Poisson regression.
3. GDP is often quite skewed and thus I take the log.

Check out the following code.

I generate a dataset with some positive correlation between `church` and `log_gdp` and then the plot of the predicted counts:

```
clear
set obs 10000
egen year = seq(), from(1990) to(2015)
bysort year: egen city = seq(), from(1) to(400)
gen gdp = rnormal(3000,1000)
gen log_gdp=log(gdp)
gen disturb=1+int((10)*runiform())
gen church = int(log_gdp+disturb)

xtset city year
xtpoisson church log_gdp, fe robust
margins, at(log_gdp=(0.35(0.1)8.8)) predict(iru0)
marginsplot
```

Which produces this:
[image: xtpoisson marginsplit]

Comment: There is no assumption in regression that the response must be continuous, let alone normally distributed; in particular OLS implies no assumptions whatsoever about any marginal distribution. At most its least important assumption is about the error distribution. I agree with your suggestion that a Poisson model is likely to be more appropriate for number of churches as response, but the main reasons are that such a model guarantees positive predictions for a response that cannot be negative and that its functional form and variance assumptions are likely to be closer to that observed.

Comment: Similarly logging variables like GDP is often helpful, but pulling in outliers and reducing skewness need not be the main reason. Naturally we can't comment on precisely what is helpful with the OP's data, which we can't see.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand the use of log and Poisson, but I am a little confused, because in the graph from Cantoni, 2014, which I attached at the beginning of the question, the x axis is year and y axis is coefficient estimate of the independent variable. It seems the marginsplot you drew and that graph are talking about different things.